# Compress all JS files in subfolders using YUI compressor .NET

Tags: .net, msbuild, compression, yui-compressor

In my project inside the "Scripts" folder I have many sub-directories. I want to minify each and every js file with output to be named as **"respective-subdirectory/file_name.min.js"**.  For that I am using below code in my BundleConfig.xml files:

```
<Target Name="Minify"> 
   <CreateItem Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Scripts\*\*.js;">
      <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="JsFiles"/>
   </CreateItem>

   <JavaScriptCompressorTask
    SourceFiles="@(JsFiles)"
    DeleteSourceFiles="false"
    OutputFile="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Scripts\*\%(JsFiles.Filename).min.js"
    CompressionType="Standard"
    LoggingType="Info"
    LineBreakPosition="-1"
   />
</Target>
```

When I place "*\" in my OutputFile tag, I am getting build error. So can someone please guide me how to achieve this (each minified file should be placed in respective subdirectory only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First to compress each file individually (to not merge them), you need to batch over the JavascriptCompresor Task using the % instead of the @ in the SourceFiles.

Second, you may use ** in the include path and %(RecursiveDir) replacing it in the JavascriptCompressor Task.

I'm currently not able to test but I think something like the following should work :

```
<Target Name="Minify"> 
   <CreateItem Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Scripts\**\*.js;">
      <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="JsFiles"/>
   </CreateItem>

   <JavaScriptCompressorTask
    SourceFiles="@(JsFiles)"
    DeleteSourceFiles="false"
    OutputFile="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Scripts\%(JsFiles.RecursiveDir)\%(JsFiles.Filename).min.js"
    CompressionType="Standard"
    LoggingType="Info"
    LineBreakPosition="-1"
   />
</Target>
```

For more information about RecursiveDir, you may read this article : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164313.aspx

Comment: Thanks @Benamin for your answer. Actually that didn't work for me. I had to use the "%(RelativeDir)" as below code to make it work. Please let me know if I am wrong:

    <JavaScriptCompressorTask
         SourceFiles="@(JsFiles)"
        DeleteSourceFiles="false"
        OutputFile="%(RelativeDir)%(JsFiles.Filename)min.js"
        CompressionType="Standard"
        LoggingType="Info"
        LineBreakPosition="-1"
     />

Comment: I'm not able to test right now but if you get your minified files in thé right directory that should be good. RecursiveDir replaces the ** part in the include path I modified. RelativeDir is fine the way you use it with a single * in the include.